# How to make the Mappings for the Objects on elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, elastic-stack, amazon-emr, elasticsearch-5

I have an index with name cart and when the user buy some products I am adding the info in the JSON as

```
{
userid:2323,
products:{
 product1.id:timestamp
 product2.id:timestamp
}
}
```

when some one purchases some products I am adding them into the products field with key as the product id and the value as the purschase time.

How to make the mapping for these type?

currently I got the **Limit of total fields in index** error as the elasticsearch was counting the each product id inside the products object as the field

Answer (score 1):

In order to prevent field balooning you'd want your `products` to be a list of objects:

```
{
  "userid": 2323,
  "products": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "timestamp": timestamp
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "timestamp": timestamp
    }
  ]
}
```

so that you can query by `products.id` and `products.timestamp`.

Caveat: lists/arrays of objects are flattened in such a way that the connections between the individual object items are lost. Use [`nested` fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) to prevent that.